# Last logged in domain user - computer name

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

Is there an easy way from the domain controller to find out the computer name that a domain user last logged into?

Comment: The age old sysadmin question. See below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a logon script to save the data somewhere (like the Description field at the computer or a file to a network folder which contains the computer name and username)

Or using third-party utilities that scans your computers and displays a list of logged users.

Comment: Not the only ways, but a good answer nonetheless.